# Анимация до края экрана

Tags: android, android-xml

Есть элемент (кнопка ) она занимает пол экрана и прибита к левому краю экрана. И есть вот такая анимация

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="250"
/>
```

ею я сдвигаю кнопку вправо на заданное расстояние.
Как можно задать ей параметр так, что  бы правый край кнопки сдвигался ровно до правого края экрана?

Доп. вопрос: как сделать анимацию кнопки плавной. В смысле что бы при плавном сдвиге вправо - не было резкого рывка назад!

Comment: На вскидку - минимум тремя способами можно сделать это, вам необходимо использовать именно данную анимацию или можно как-то по своему?

Comment: Сейчас опыт работы с анимацией у меня не большой, поэтому с удовольствием посмотрел на ваши варианты. На всякий случай добавлю что объект который я пытаюсь анимировать - это RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В смысле что бы при плавном сдвиге вправо - не было резкого рывка назад!

Вам необходимо использовать для этого `ObjectAnimator`. Пример:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourButton, "x", yourButton.getX(), button.getX()+200)
                        .setDuration(500)
                        .start();
```

В данном варианте берем текущую позицию и сдвигаем кнопку на 200. Там она и остается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы прибить к краю возьмите текущее положение, ширину экрана, размер кнопки и подвиньте на необходимое расстояние.